# HAPROXY INGRESS IN K8S CAN NOT START

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, kubernetes-ingress, haproxy-ingress

I am using https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/ haproxy ingress

When i deploy all in k8s the `quay.io/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress` container start error,

the log print below:

```
I0512 09:31:19.876527       6 launch.go:151] 

Name:       HAProxy

Release:    v0.8.3

Build:      git-ae30511

Repository: https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress

I0512 09:31:19.876936       6 launch.go:154] Watching for ingress class: haproxy

I0512 09:31:19.878217       6 launch.go:364] Creating API client for https://10.0.0.1:443

I0512 09:31:42.274632       6 main.go:45] Shutting down with signal terminated

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x68 pc=0x1036b9b]


goroutine 37 [running]:

github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress/pkg/controller.(*HAProxyController).Stop(0xc4203bc0e0, 0x1c, 0xc42001f790)

    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress/pkg/controller/controller.go:186 +0x3b
main.handleSignal(0xc4203bc0e0, 0xc4204361e0)

    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress/pkg/main.go:46 +0x163

created by main.main

    /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress/pkg/main.go:30 +0x88
```

can someone help me thanks lot;

Comment: How exactly are you trying to deploy it? What are the commands that you are using and on which k8s version?

Comment: It sounds to me that the controller is trying to connect to the apiserver and the liveness is killing the process. Try to temporarily remove the liveness and check if you can see a timeout error or whatever.